# Spring Tool Suite Pivotal TC Server failing to start up

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I just now installed Spring Tool Suite on my system (Windows 7), which is behind a proxy by the way, and after Installing I tried starting the Pivotal TC Server but it did n't start

On pressing the details tab of the error message I got this

```
  Publishing the configuration...
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified) C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\catalina.properties: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\context.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.access: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.password: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.password (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.password (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\server.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\tomcat-users.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\web.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Can this be because I dont have admin rights for the system?

Comment: I would recommend to install STS (including tc Server) into a location with full read/write access rights. Otherwise tc Server will not be able to create the appropriate instances.

Comment: Even running as Admin is not solving the problem.

Comment: Are the files that tc Server is complaining about there? And what happens if you install STS into a different location with full user rights?